# Vue bind SVG transform rotate

Tags: svg, vue.js, rotation, bind

Trying to rotate an svg group by an amount deg in

```
data():{ 
     deg: 90,
     groupCenter: [100,200]
}
```

I have searched but can't find the correct syntax to bind data to the svg rotate function,

```
:transform="{'rotate(' + deg + ' ' + groupCenter[0] + ' ' + groupCenter[1] + ')'}"
```

I am trying to add this to a circle like this,

```
<circle style="mix-blend-mode: multiply;" v-for="(el,index) in element.coords" :fill="el.color" :key="index" :r="el.radius" :cy="el.y" :cx="el.x" :transform="{'rotate(' + deg + ' ' + groupCenter[0] + ' ' + groupCenter[1] + ')'}" />
```

I get,

```
- invalid expression: Unexpected token + in

    {'rotate(' + deg + ' ' + groupCenter[0] + ' ' + groupCenter[1] + ')'}

  Raw expression: :transform="{'rotate(' + deg + ' ' + groupCenter[0] + ' ' + groupCenter[1] + ')'}"
```

SOLUTION:

This worked for me using a method,

```
:transform="rotateShape(index)"
```

And the method,

```
rotateShape(){
              return "rotate(" + this.deg + " 0 0)"
            },
```

But I don't know why the initial attempt wouldn't work.

Comment: did you try to remove the {} from :transform:'{..}'

Comment: No I didn't try that. But I got it working using a method.

Comment: please try it and tell me

Comment: With and without {} same issue.

Comment: `data():{ ...` it's not a valid syntax try to remove `:`

Answer (score 1):

The transform attribute needs to evaluate to a string - i.e. `transform="rotate(90deg)"`, so I think you need to concatenate some partial strings:

```
:transform="'rotate(' + deg + ' deg)'"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great place to use javascript's [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
:transform="`rotate(${deg} deg)`"
```